# Creating an animating indicator arrow on iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

I am trying to achieve a similar effect to the indicator  arrow found in iOS's Music app, as you scroll past a certain point it changes from an arrow to a single line. I've attached a slowed down example below.

[image: Example animation]

The point I'm struggling to understand is the arrow itself, I've tried to use two rotated `UIView`s as lines positioned together with constraints and have successfully created an animation using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` and keyframes. But unfortunately the lines intrude over each other when going from an arrow to line.

I'm unsure of the correct method to achieve this example. Any push in the right direction to achieving this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to animate the path of a CAShapeLayer. This gives you the rounded ends and the mitred join for free. You need a straight path and a bent path; switch from one to the other. The straight path must consist of two segments to match the two segments of the bent path.

Here's my simulation of your animation:

[image]

Here's the configuration of the shape layer and its paths:

```
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.frame = // ...        
    shape.lineCap = .round
    shape.lineJoin = .miter
    shape.lineWidth = 6
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    let p1 = UIBezierPath()
    p1.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:35))
    p1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:20, y:35))
    p1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:40, y:35))
    let straight = p1.cgPath

    let p2 = UIBezierPath()
    p2.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:25))
    p2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:20, y:30))
    p2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:40, y:25))
    let bent = p2.cgPath
```

Then it's just a matter of alternating the `path` of `shape` between `straight` and `bent` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to achieve this using SwiftUI, you can implement this by creating an object conforming to the `Shape` protocol. The benefit of this is that you can leverage the `animatableData` property as a variable to define your shape, simplifying the animation process ([Advanced SwiftUI Animations – Part 1: Paths](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part1/) does a good job of introducing this concept).

```swift
struct ChevronShape: Shape {
    var pointingUp: Bool
    private var heightOffset: CGFloat
    
    init(pointingUp: Bool) {
        self.pointingUp = pointingUp
        self.heightOffset = pointingUp ? 1 : 0
    }
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return heightOffset }
        set { heightOffset = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height
        
        let horizontalCenter = width / 2
        let horizontalCenterOffset = width * 0.15
        let arrowTipStartingPoint = height - heightOffset * height * 0.7
        
        path.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: horizontalCenter - horizontalCenterOffset, y: arrowTipStartingPoint))

        /// User of quad-curve to achieve "roudning effect" at arrow tip
        path.addQuadCurve(to: .init(x: horizontalCenter + horizontalCenterOffset, y: arrowTipStartingPoint), control: .init(x: horizontalCenter, y: height * (1 - heightOffset)))
        
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: width, y: height))

        return path
    }
}
```

The above shape can now be used as any other SwiftUI view, with the following considerations-

- The `pointingUp` parameter determines the state of the shape and hence needs to be encapsulated within a property that affects the state of the view hierarchy (I've used `@State` in the example below).
- You can either use explicit or implicit animations to trigger the animation by modifying the above state. I've used explicit animation below as it is more clear in conveying the action taking place on this occasion.
- `Shape` objects are really flexible in how they are represented. The flip side of this is that they need additional modifiers in order to achieve the desired look.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pointingUp = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChevronShape(pointingUp: pointingUp)
                /// Modifiers affecting general shape
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
                .frame(width: 60, height: 15)
                /// Non-essential Modifiers
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .opacity(0.6)
                /// Interaction modifiers
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) { self.pointingUp.toggle() }
                }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

And here is the end result-

[image]